# identifying numbers that follow substrings without space

Tags: python, regex

I have a body of text:

> Although the same genomic DNA is packaged in the nucleus of each cell,
>   different sets of genes are expressed in different cell states1,2.
>   Despite significant progress over the past decade, there are still
>   many unanswered questions about how the genome is organized within the
>   nucleus and how this changes across different cell states3–7. About 20% of these facts are true. In this
>   view, genome organization is largely organized around chromosome
>   territories, such that most DNA interactions occur within an
>   individual chromosome10,20–22. These interactions include chromatin
>   loops that connect specific genomic DNA regions such as enhancers and
>   promoters23–25, local interacting neighborhoods of DNA called
>   topologically associated domains (TADs)26–28, and compartments where
>   DNA regions interact based on their transcriptional activity (A/B
>   compartments)5,9,29,30. However, the extent to which DNA interactions
>   occur between chromosomes has been controversial9,10,20,24,31,32. The
>   second view is primarily derived from in situ imaging of DNA, RNA, and
>   protein in the nucleus using microscopy. In this view, the genome is
>   also organized around structures such as nuclear bodies that typically
>   concentrate DNA, RNA, and protein molecules that are associated with
>   shared functional or regulatory roles within the nucleus33–37. These
>   include nuclear bodies associated with ribosomal RNA transcription,
>   processing, and biogenesis (nucleolus)16,33,38, .... These
>   observations, and others8,11,13,52–54, demonstrate that genome
>   interactions can occur beyond chromosome territories10,20,48,55.

I want to re-write this text having omitted all of the numbers that immediately come after words.

Desired output:

> Although the same genomic DNA is packaged in the nucleus of each cell, different sets of
>   genes are expressed in different cell states. Despite significant
>   progress over the past decade, there are still many unanswered
>   questions about how the genome is organized within the nucleus and how
>   this changes across different cell states. About 20% of these facts are true. In this view, genome
>   organization is largely organized around chromosome territories, such
>   that most DNA interactions occur within an individual chromosome.
>   These interactions include chromatin loops that connect specific
>   genomic DNA regions such as enhancers and promoters, local interacting
>   neighborhoods of DNA called topologically associated domains (TADs),
>   and compartments where DNA regions interact based on their
>   transcriptional activity (A/B compartments). However, the extent to
>   which DNA interactions occur between chromosomes has been
>   controversial. The second view is primarily derived from in situ
>   imaging of DNA, RNA, and protein in the nucleus using microscopy. In
>   this view, the genome is also organized around structures such as
>   nuclear bodies that typically concentrate DNA, RNA, and protein
>   molecules that are associated with shared functional or regulatory
>   roles within the nucleus. These include nuclear bodies associated with
>   ribosomal RNA transcription, processing, and biogenesis (nucleolus),
>   .... These observations, and others, demonstrate that genome
>   interactions can occur beyond chromosome territories.

I have tried a range of regular expressions to do this but I am not experienced:

```
import re
x = re.sub(r"(?<=\w)\d+(?:,\d+)*", "", x)
x = re.sub(r"(?<=\))\d+(?:,\d+)*", "", x)
x = re.sub(r"(?<=\w)\-(?:,\d+)*", "", x)
```

As of the now the above code only manages to omit certain undesired properties:

> Although the same genomic DNA is packaged in the nucleus of each cell,
>   different sets of genes are expressed in different cell states.
>   Despite significant progress over the past decade, there are still
>   many unanswered questions about how the genome is organized within the
>   nucleus and how this changes across different cell states–7. About 20% of these facts are true. For
>   example, it remains unclear whether interchromosomal interactions play
>   an important role in shaping genome organization–1. There are
>   currently two distinct and poorly reconciled views of genome
>   organization that are derived from different technologies. The first
>   view is primarily derived from genomewide proximity ligation methods,
>   which work by ligating the ends of DNA regions that are in close
>   spatial proximity in the nucleus followed by sequencing to map
>   interactions 1–1. In this view, genome organization is largely
>   organized around chromosome territories, such that most DNA
>   interactions occur within an individual chromosoME 1–2. These
>   interactions include chromatin loops that connect specific genomic DNA
>   regions such as enhancers and promoters–2, local interacting
>   neighborhoods of DNA called topologically associated domains 2–2, and
>   compartments where DNA regions interact based on their transcriptional
>   activity 5,9,2. However, the extent to which DNA interactions occur
>   between chromosomes has been controversial. The second view is
>   primarily derived from in situ imaging of DNA, RNA, and protein in the
>   nucleus using microscopy. In this view, the genome is also organized
>   around structures such as nuclear bodies that typically concentrate
>   DNA, RNA, and protein molecules that are associated with shared
>   functional or regulatory roles within the nucleus–3. These include
>   nuclear bodies associated with ribosomal RNA transcription,
>   processing, and biogenesis 1, spliceosomal complex assembly 3, and
>   storage of mRNA processing and splicing factors 4–4, among others.
>   There is evidence that specific interchromosomal interactions can
>   occur at these nuclear bodies. For example, nucleoli are formed around
>   the active transcription of ribosomal DNA genes that are present
>   across several distinct chromosomes. In addition, specific actively
>   transcribed genes from different chromosomes can localize near the
>   periphery of nuclear speckles–5. These observations, and others–5,
>   demonstrate that genome interactions can occur beyond chromosome
>   territories

Comment: @Roars x = re.sub(r"([\d\-\–]\,?)+", "", x) returns 'SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

#### Option 1

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/rsMMfm/3)

```
(?<=[^\s\d])\d(?:[^a-zA-Z]*\d)?
```

#### Option 2

**Note**: This option uses the `i` flag (case-insensitive)

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/rsMMfm/4)

```
(?<=[a-z)])\d(?:[^a-z]*\d)?
```

This allows number lists in sentences. What I would suggest, if that's the case, however, is to use the following regex and add any additional characters in the list `[)]` (in the second positive lookbehind) to ensure *special characters* are preceded by a letter.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/rsMMfm/5)

```
(?:(?<=[a-z])|(?<=[a-z][)]))\d(?:[^a-z]*\d)?
```

---

### Results

#### Input

> Although the same genomic DNA is packaged in the nucleus of each cell,
>   different sets of genes are expressed in different cell states1,2.
>   Despite significant progress over the past decade, there are still
>   many unanswered questions about how the genome is organized within the
>   nucleus and how this changes across different cell states3–7. About
>   20% of these facts are true. In this view, genome organization is
>   largely organized around chromosome territories, such that most DNA
>   interactions occur within an individual chromosome10,20–22. These
>   interactions include chromatin loops that connect specific genomic DNA
>   regions such as enhancers and promoters23–25, local interacting
>   neighborhoods of DNA called topologically associated domains
>   (TADs)26–28, and compartments where DNA regions interact based on
>   their transcriptional activity (A/B compartments)5,9,29,30. However,
>   the extent to which DNA interactions occur between chromosomes has
>   been controversial9,10,20,24, 31,32. The second view is primarily
>   derived from in situ imaging of DNA, RNA, and protein in the nucleus
>   using microscopy. In this view, the genome is also organized around
>   structures such as nuclear bodies that typically concentrate DNA, RNA,
>   and protein molecules that are associated with shared functional or
>   regulatory roles within the nucleus33–37. These include nuclear bodies
>   associated with ribosomal RNA transcription, processing, and
>   biogenesis (nucleolus)16,33,38, .... These observations, and
>   others8,11,13,52–54, demonstrate that genome interactions can occur
>   beyond chromosome territories10,20,48,55.

#### Output

> Although the same genomic DNA is packaged in the nucleus of each cell,
>   different sets of genes are expressed in different cell states.
>   Despite significant progress over the past decade, there are still
>   many unanswered questions about how the genome is organized within the
>   nucleus and how this changes across different cell states. About 20%
>   of these facts are true. In this view, genome organization is largely
>   organized around chromosome territories, such that most DNA
>   interactions occur within an individual chromosome. These interactions
>   include chromatin loops that connect specific genomic DNA regions such
>   as enhancers and promoters, local interacting neighborhoods of DNA
>   called topologically associated domains (TADs), and compartments where
>   DNA regions interact based on their transcriptional activity (A/B
>   compartments). However, the extent to which DNA interactions occur
>   between chromosomes has been controversial. The second view is
>   primarily derived from in situ imaging of DNA, RNA, and protein in the
>   nucleus using microscopy. In this view, the genome is also organized
>   around structures such as nuclear bodies that typically concentrate
>   DNA, RNA, and protein molecules that are associated with shared
>   functional or regulatory roles within the nucleus. These include
>   nuclear bodies associated with ribosomal RNA transcription,
>   processing, and biogenesis (nucleolus), .... These observations, and
>   others, demonstrate that genome interactions can occur beyond
>   chromosome territories.

---

### Explanation

- `(?<=[^\s\d])` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes is not a space or digit character
- `\d` Match any digit character
- `(?:[^a-zA-Z]*\d)?` Match the following zero or one times. This exists to remove the possibility of a single digit following a word such as `states1` (where what follows does not include another digit).

  - `[^a-zA-Z]*` Match any number of any character not present in the set `a-zA-Z` (anything except ASCII letters)
  - `\d` Match any digit character

Comment: good answer, but should it be this instead:
`(?<=[^\s\d])(?:\d[^a-zA-Z]*\d)`

Comment: actually even that with that edit it still accepts numbers after the first when a space is before

Comment: @Roars the regex works as is. The point of `\d(?:[^a-zA-Z]*\d)?` is to match a single digit **or** any number of anything except ASCII letters, followed by a digit (in the case of a list for example i.e. `1,2`)

Comment: The problem I see is: `chromosome10,20–22`. If you add a space after `chromosome`, it would still match/remove `20-22`

Comment: @Roars In that case, the OP should use [`(?<=[a-z)])\d(?:[^a-z]*\d)?`](https://regex101.com/r/rsMMfm/4) with `i` flag

Comment: Nice. I think that is what OP wants :)

Comment: @Roars thanks! I've updated my answer to include the regex I specified in the comments, as well as an additional one that includes another method to ensuring letters precede the digit or the special character between the digit and the letter.